# How to use code in a catchError code block

Tags: angular, rxjs

I don't know the correct syntax for this, how do I use a block of code in the catchError?

```
this.budgetService.getBudgetDays(this.startDate, this.finishDate)
        .pipe(
          catchError(res => self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate))
        )
        .subscribe(res => {
          console.log('Response = ', res);
          self.timelineBudgetDates = self.processDates(res);
          //self.timelineBudgetDates = res;

        });
```

So I want to use something like this where I can assign a value to timelineDates.

```
.pipe(
  catchError(self.timelineDates = self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate)
  // more code...

  )
)
```

Comment: The [documentation page](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) clarifies usage fairly well. The point is that the argument to `catchError` should be a function that receives two arguments: an error object and the source observable.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this

```
.pipe(
 catchError(err => {
  self.timelineDates = self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate);
  console.error(err.message);
  console.log("Error is handled");
  return throwError("Error thrown from catchError");
 })
 // more code...
)
```

Learn details from here https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-catcherror

Answer (score 0):

`catchError` needs a callback function as parameter.

```ts
.pipe(
  catchError(() => {
    self.timelineDates = self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate
  })
  // more code...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`catchError` is just a function

```js
.pipe(
  catchError(error => {
      console.log({error});
     self.timelineDates = self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate)
  // more code...but return an observable
 return of('some return value, maybe null, maybe a good default');
    }
  )
)
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

```js
// RxJS v6+
import { throwError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
//emit error
const source = throwError('This is an error!');
//gracefully handle error, returning observable with error message
const example = source.pipe(catchError(val => of(`I caught: ${val}`)));
//output: 'I caught: This is an error'
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```